# change format Date in Asp mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i'am looking to change my format date but i can't do this .
i want to change format date like this :
("08-04-2020 12:00:00")

```
Code Source:
                      eventAllocation.StartDate = DateTime.Parse("08-04-2020 12:00:00");
```

I want to put a transformation for date start

```
   eventAllocation.StartDate = DateTime.Parse(ar.startingDateTime).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

i try but show me error 
i want make the date like format ("08-04-2020 12:00:00")

Comment: You're trying to take a DateTime, convert it to a string with a specific format, then Parse it again in the same line?  Why transform it at all if you just go from one DateTime to another?  The underlying value is the same.  Anyway, I think your code's error is in the placement of the parentheses:  try `eventAllocation.StartDate = DateTime.Parse(ar.startingDateTime.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"));`

Comment: thank you but he show an error like cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.IFormatProvider'

Comment: I think that Sean is missing a ')' after "(ar" in the above.  Something like the below should work for you:

`string ar = "08-04-2020 12:00:00";`
`Console.WriteLine("Hello World");`
`Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Parse(ar).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"));`
  
`string dateToFormat = "2020-01-02 12:34pm";`
`Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Parse(dateToFormat).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"));`